# Search in mysql column against provided json value

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a table contents. Columns -> id, title, description.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contents` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

-- Dumping data for table `contents`--

```
INSERT INTO `contents` (`id`, `title`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'My fab phone', 'I own an iphone 5c.'),
(2, 'I hate my phone', 'I have a Samsung S4. :(');
```

I have a json vaue made by input from user. Its like ->

```
[{"devices":"iPhone 5c"},{"devices":"Samsung S4"}]
```

I would like to search against it against the title, description comlumn in mysql.. my application is in php. is it even possible in mysql ? or I have to manipulate the json run it in loop and then simple search in mysql ? ...If its possible in mysql then please help

Comment: you can parse the json in mysql using common_schema

Comment: I can't really use common_schema coz that requires installation and its a shared server.. but still thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert table in MyISAM storage engine

```
SELECT  *
FROM    pages
WHERE   MATCH(title, description) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This will be much faster if you create a `FULLTEXT` index on your columns:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fx_pages_title_description ON pages (title, description)
```

, but will work even without the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use common_schema like this

```
select common_schema.extract_json_value(t.title,'/title') , common_schema.extract_json_value(t.description,'/description') from contents t ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `contents`
WHERE
    (`title` = 'iPhone 5c' AND `description` = 'iPhone 5c')
    OR
    (`title` = 'iPhone 5c' OR `description` = 'iPhone 5c');
```